# Extra character in Python character count (Fedora, Gedit)

Tags: python, fedora, gedit

I'm running Fedora, Python 2.7, and Gedit and getting a strange error in what should be a simple character count function:

```
    def charCount(text):
        text.seek(0)
        # read the whole file as one string
        full_string = text.read()
        char_count = len(full_string)
        # return the count
        return char_count
```

Running this on my Mac gets the right count, but on my Fedora comp I keep getting 1 extra in the count. My main() is just reading in a file specified by the user and calling this function on it. Any ideas where the extra character is coming from? Thanks!

(This is my first question here. Sorry if I did anything wrong!)

Comment: Can you check the length of the input file by running `wc input_file.txt`?  Your code works for me on Linux.

Comment: Hi Tony. For a file with just the letter "a" (no spaces or new lines), wc is returning "1 1 2." And when run with "-m" it is returning "2."

Comment: Editors will often add the newline even if you don't ask them too.  If you do `od -tx1z input_file.txt` what is the last hex character?  If it's `0a`, there's a newline.

Comment: Yup! That's it. Thank you! This had been really bugging me.

Comment: Happy to be of service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a newline at the end of the file that you were not expecting.

You can get rid of a single character at the end of the file with the linux commands `truncate -s $(($(wc -m myfile | cut -d' ' -f1)-1)) myfile`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a rapid guess here. This might be about line terminations. Some systems use '\r\n', some other '\n' only. I think that osx uses '\r' only.

Depending on the platform, len will count one of those or not and will return a slightly different count

Comment: Hi Eric. I tried running it on a test file with just the letter "a" and no newlines, tabs, or spaces. It's still returning 2 for some reason.

Comment: It is most likely that your file has termination of some sort. Try looping over each character, convert them to their string representation and then print them